# Building Kernel Image for Embedded Linux Platform

Tags: linux-kernel, busybox, cross-compilation, u-boot, root-filesystem

I am interested in compiling a linux image for Ingenic SoC based platform. The vendor vaguely provided instruction on how to compile the linux kernel for the target SoC. So based on vendor instructions and online search the following are needed to have an image of the embedded linux for the platform.

> 1. Compile the toolchain (mipsel for mips based architecture)
> 2. Compile the linux kernel with given drivers/BSP using the toolchain
> 3. Compile the root file system - Busybox suggested (dont know why)
> 4. Compile uBoot for target SoC
> 5. Partition the storage such as sd with target specific partition table
> 6. Flash the whole image into sd

So the questions are, why root file system is separate from kernel image?
What role does busybox play in generating file system? Also if the linux image is compiled without root file system how to merge the two to have drivers in /sys directory in the root file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building embedded linux is an extremely broad yet very arcane topic, not sure if it has a good fit in either the EE.SE or the Unix/Linux.SE site.

Some of the books that address your questions can be found here:

Linux From Scratch (LFS)
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/
"Derived from the popular Linux-From-Scratch-HOWTO, this book describes the process of creating your own Linux system from scratch from an already installed Linux distribution, using nothing but the sources of software that are needed."

This book is part of the Linux Documentation Project:
https://www.tldp.org/guides.html

I can see from your previous questions (on EE.SE) that you're self-learning about embedded systems, so this is recommended reading. Linux from Scratch assumes that you're building a Linux distribution on a PC, for the same PC; that's separate from the problem of cross-compiling to target a different system other than a PC.

Additional recommended reading (also on TLDP guides link above):

- Bash Guide for Beginners
- Introduction to Linux - A Hands on Guide
- GNU/Linux Command-Line Tools Summary
- Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide
- The Linux System Administrators' Guide
- The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide (if you get into writing device drivers)
- Custom Linux: A Porting Guide - Porting LinuxPPC to a Custom SBC

Also checkout Embedded Linux Wiki, https://elinux.org/Main_Page

You might consider starting with a more commonly-supported embedded target system, like Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone, where there is a lot of existing support. Much better chance of project success if you start by building a fairly current distribution on your PC, then build fairly current distribution to run on the embedded target system. It's essentially the same problem but lots more people can help with specific questions about building Raspian(Debian Stretch), very few people will even attempt to guess about Ingeninc SoC specifically. See for example this question on RaspberryPi.SE: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3196/building-kernel-image-img-including-ramdisk

> Why root file system is separate from kernel image?

That's how Linux was designed. The kernel image is executable code that runs in kernel space (at startup, and with special privileges), and the root file system is its data. Doesn't make sense to combine the two, except when building the boot media for a specific target system.

> What role does busybox play in generating the file system?

None. Busybox incorporates several of the most-used Unix utilities into the shell executable.

Tradidional Unix favored lots of small, independent utility programs; in contrast, the Busybox approach bundles several of the most-used utilities as shell built-ins. Busybox is a good choice to include in the target system's root filesystem because it provides a lot of useful utilities in a fairly small, convenient package.

The "Linux from Scratch" guide follows the traditional, non-Busybox approach. I'd recommend first going through the process without worrying about whether to include Busybox for your target system.

> if the linux image is compiled without root file system how to merge the two to have drivers in /sys directory in the root file system?

The device drivers are either built as part of the kernel image, or else they are separate Loadable Kernel Modules that are optionally loaded during the boot process.

Although the term "file" usually means a bitstream that is stored on a non-volatile memory device like a hard disk or a USB stick, "file" can also mean any temporary bunch of data bits that has a name or some other kind of handle. There are some special, dynamically-generated files in /proc, /sys, and /dev that are generated by the kernel, and that are mounted on top of the root filesystem's empty /proc /sys and /dev placeholders.

Comment: good explanation. So I have a question. The link you provided on raspberry pi says that the file system is merged with kernel image using "initramfs", Is there any tool that can automatically merge the kernel with the file system?

Comment: Also one of the motivation to separate the kernel from rootfs is to allow users to install custom software packages in the file system and build a custom Linux with software packages pre-installed. Rght?